# Scalable solution for combining image streams on the server

Tags: image, stream, scalability

I'm building an application on Node.js meant to serve image compositions (overlays of multiple images served as one image).  The user can select up to ten images and combine them.  We want to serve a final composition of the selected images quickly and without saving it onto the server.  We think using streams is the best way to do this, because reading all the images would eat up our memory.  Is it possible to combine the image streams on the fly and serve the final composition?

For example, is this pipeline possible:

- Create readable stream for the multiple individual images from the database into the server.
- Combine the image streams
- Pipe the composition to the user

Comment: What do you mean when you are talking about stream of images from database to server?

Comment: All of my images are stored on an S3.  The database has the url of where the images are stored.  
I want to stream in the images from the S3 on the server so I don't have to load all the images into memory before I combine them. 
Does that help explain it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to combine the image streams on the fly and serve the final composition?

I don't think it's possible to read images as a stream, because of compression algorithms. They are just not designed to do that. It's possible though if you will store images in raw (bitmap) format, but storage requirements will grow up significantly.

Regarding scalability. Scalability basically means – *more work could be done if you'll give system more resources*. In that sense *your problem is scalable* by nature. All you need is to deploy more instances of process doing images overlay and put them behind some sort of balancer (it's quite easy if you're using HTTP as your application protocol).

So, scalability should not be a problem for your system, I think. But performance and efficiency could be.

Speaking of performance, image overlay require a lot of computation to be done, so computation should be done efficiently. So what I recommend is to find some library for you platform that can do image overlays efficiently, or alternatively , a way to integrate such library in your platform. Consider using [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), for example.

Basically, any library which allows you to perform massive parallel operations on matrices will do. Because this is what image overlay operation by it's nature.

Another solution is to use GPU, as those devices are particularly created for those type of problems and allows to perform massively parallel operations on images. Of course using GPU is a restriction on a deployment scheme of application. So it not an option in most cases.

Comment: You can definitely read image streams and then immediately pipe that out as a response.  For example, the following comment works great.
I'm still not sure how to composite multiple incoming streams on the fly / or if it's possible.

Comment: `app.get('/creative_health_check3', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'image/png'});
    var rstream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/MobileImages/MaleBack10002.png');
    rstream.pipe(res);
})`

Comment: It's because you're reading stream of bytes but not an image. What I mean is that you can not work with stream of bytes like with image, because you need to decode it first.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks. 
Can you encrypt the chunks of the stream, composite those chunks, and then pipe that out?